# Square delay_capture to charge partially on capture_transaction

Tags: python-3.x, square-connect, square

I want to clarify if it's possible to change the amount to be charged on a capture_transaction call. Say on charge endpoint I authorize a $5 and delayed the capture, but when capturing transaction I only want to charge the customer $4.

From reading the docs, it doesn't really provide any parameter to change the amount. Is there any way to do this?

https://github.com/square/connect-python-sdk/blob/master/docs/TransactionsApi.md#endpoint-charge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this. You cannot edit a transaction (even if it's set to `delay_capture`) after it's created.

Your best bet would be saving the card on file (using `CreateCustomerCard`) and then charging the card at a later date for whatever amount you need.

Save cards on file: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/cookbook/save-cards-on-file

Charge cards on file: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/cookbook/charge-cards-on-file